# Have mutliple urls to point to the same GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have multiple websites on GCS buckets for our subdomains:

- site1.oursite.com
- site2.oursite.com
- site3.oursite.com

How to make **www** to work as well with these subdomains, so that we have:

- www.site1.oursite.com
- www.site2.oursite.com
- www.site3.oursite.com

to point to right bucket.

Comment: I would suggest using a CNAME instead.

Comment: you mean cname for each subdomain? That would be tricky, I have hundreds of them. I just point the main domain to cloudstorage CNAME and that forwards everything in that direction

Comment: Can you redirect www.site1.oursite.com to site1.oursite.com ?

Comment: that is possible, but then what is the point of using GCS bucket websites if I have to do routing myself?

Answer (score 1):

To make www to work with your sub-domains, you have to create buckets with names :

- *www.site1.oursite.com*
- *www.site2.oursite.com* etc to get access website via www.site1.oursite.com, www.site2.oursite.com.

To access URL as `www.site1.oursite.com`, you have to create a CNAME record in DNS that redirects requests from **www.site1.oursite.com to the Google Cloud Storage URI**. To accomplishing this, you need to publish the following CNAME record in DNS:

> **www.site1.oursite.com CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com**

Comment: But will it be possible one bucket to serve via both `www.site1.oursite.com` and `site1.oursite.com`?

Comment: it seems possible: *"If you want the test.example.com to serve the same content as is served from www.example.com, add a CNAME record that aliases "test" to "www". A separate bucket is not needed in this scenario."*

Answer (score 1):

I, too, believed the statement

> If you want the test.example.com to serve the same content as is served from www.example.com, add a CNAME record that aliases "test" to "www". A separate bucket is not needed in this scenario.

on the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration#tips) and tried getting this to work for hours. Interestingly, that help text seems to be the only resource on the web claiming that this works. I believe, that this is an error on the side of those persons who wrote that text.

I resorted to additional buckets with simple http redirects for now as a workaround. Obviously, that's less than ideal.

Comment: If we can't rely on documentation, what else can we rely on. Someone from Google Cloud team, can you please check/confirm this behaviour.